# Speed as a dimension

Tags: cosmology, coordinate-systems

In the Spring of 2015, I raised a question in an astronomy class about dimensions: can speed be considered a dimension?  I raised it because it seems to have a capacity.

About 10 years ago, a buddy of mine was talking about the speed of light, and what would happen if one was on a spaceship travelling at light speed and then turned on a flashlight.  This is when I learned that as a body approaches the speed of light, that everything slows down.  Also, he noted that the beam of light from the flashlight would have to bend outward.

So this is why I think speed can be a dimension: because the universe simply has no capacity for any more speed.  I know there are many definitions of dimension, but are those bound by wrongfully assumed limits?

Comment: There is [phase space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space), but it may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: You are asking about dimension in the sense of coordinates or analysis?

Answer (score 3):

Speed in itself is not a dimension. Speed is a consequence of moving from point a to point b, or moving from (x,y,z) to (x',y',z') in a certain amount of time. A dimensions in itself just describes a measurable quantity of some length. With speed, you are measuring the length you have travelled in (x,y,z). Also time will not slow down for you. You will experience time the same in your frame of reference. Also light will not bend as you approach the speed of light.